# Check undefinded keys

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I am try to automatically assign the attribute value. I need to assign value for class attribute like bellow,

```
@property (nonatomic,retain)NSString *nid;
....
[self setValue:value forKey:@"nid"];
```

instead of,

```
[self setNid:value];
```

Problem i can't find method for handle the undefined key in my class. In NSDictionary have method for this,

```
[[dictionry allKeys]containsObject:@"nid"];
```

Is there any method similar to this handle my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if it what you mean, but the NSKeyValueCoding Protocol Reference knows the function

```
- (id)valueForUndefinedKey:(NSString *)key
```

It is called in case of an unknown key in KVC.

Comment: Is this need to set any delegate. Can you give any example.

Comment: @Hasintha: I do not understand what you mean by "Is this need to set any delegate". What are you trying to reach? Why do you need the key if you have already access to the property?

Answer (score 0):

If a key could not be found, the object that was queried receives the `valueForUndefinedKey:` message. You can override its implementation to find out what the undefined key was.